# What statistical test to find significance in binomial data with small sample size?

Tags: statistics

I have a problem.

I want to find if there is a statististical significant difference between two groups which I have put through a practical test.

The outcome was 1 or 0 (success/fail).

Group 1 was subject to extra training material before the "exam".
Group 2 was not.

Each group had one attempt in three different scenarios: easy - medium - hard.

Lets take the medium scenario as example:

The number of participants in each group is 10

Group 1 scored: 7 successes, 3 failures --> success rate 0.70
Group 2 scored: 2 successes, 8 failures --> success rate 0.22

Now what I have done, is try to use the Z-test for two population proportions in an attempt to reject the null hypothesis, buuuuut, I think my sample size is to small for the z-test?

Im not sure what test to use at this point, can anyone give me a clue?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Look at Fisher's exact test, based on hypergeometric distribution.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment** continued:  Here is output from Minitab statistical software for comparing two proportions. There is a warning message for the approximate normal test. The result for Fisher's exact test is also shown (with larger P-value).

Please look at textbook, class notes, or online for a suitable explanation of Fisher's test.
(Because you have shown no work of your own, I have no way to judge your background or what level of explanation to provide.)

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample  X   N  Sample p
1       7  10  0.700000
2       2  10  0.200000

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.5
95% lower bound for difference:  0.183606
Test for difference = 0 (vs > 0):  Z = 2.60  P-Value = 0.005

* NOTE * The normal approximation may be inaccurate for small samples.


Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 0.035
```

In case it helps, here is a computation of the Fisher P-value from R statistical software:

```
sum(dhyper(0:2, 10, 10, 9))
[1] 0.03488926
```

You have an urn with 10 red balls and 10 white balls,  you withdraw 9 balls from the urn without replacement. What is the probability that two or fewer of the 9 balls drawn are red ones? Sum three terms of the appropriate hypergeometric PDF (or PMF).  [Computations by hand are a little tedious, but elementary.] Perhaps see [this Q & A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404331/how-to-infer-difference-of-population-proportion-between-two-groups-when-proport/404339#404339) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) on Fisher's test.